# Deleting association from HABTM table

Tags: cakephp

I have a Users and a Reports table, connected with HABTM relationship.

I can save a report that creates a correct record in `reports_users` table, I can view the relationship table by using `$this->User->ReportsUser->..`, and so on.

Now I want to delete a specific row in reports_users table, but I can't seem to do it.

I have tried the following:

```
$this->User->ReportsUser->deleteAll(array(
    'ReportsUser.report_id' => $this->data['Report']['report_id'], 
    'ReportsUser.user_id' => $this->data['Report']['user_id']
));
```

..but it deletes all the rows with the given user_id, with this query:

[image: Bad delete query]

What am I doing wrong here. Is it a bad data in the deleteAll call?

I don't want to delete any users or reports, only the relationship between them.

I can confirm that the table names are correct, and that the variables exist and are set.

Comment: I can't see much wrong here. Can you make sure that the column name is indeed `report_id`?

Comment: @Magnus, Yep, I am sure.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `user_id` condition? What is the generated query?

Answer (score 1):

It seems no error with your code. Either your `$this->data['ReportUser']['report_id']` is having some problem. The best way is to first try to print your `$this->data`. And check whether it exists?

For the safety reasons, use the second argument `$cascade = false` and also unbind all the ReportUser model Associationship using `$this->ReportUser->unbindModel()` method.

The other reason seems to be deleting data through 
`$this->User->ReportUser. Try to use $this->ReportUser->deleteAll('your conditions', false);` directly.

Please ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. $this->ReportUser is not an object for me, I can only use $this->User->ReportsUser.. All the variables exist.